# Time complexity function

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

I'm not sure I should post this on the Mathematics website or the Computer science website of Stack Exchange. If I'm wrong I will replace my question.

So I'm trying to calculate the time complexity of a given algorithm. I've reached this point of the calculation and I know it's correct:
$$
T(n)\leq 2+2^{h+1}(h-1).
$$
Now I know I have to reach this solution:
$$
T(n)\leq 2n\lg(n)+2.
$$
Because this is true: $$2^{h}\leq n < 2^{h+1}.$$

I really have no idea how to get there. I think it's very easy, but for some reason I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking logs of the last inequality, we see that
$$h \leqslant \lg n < h+1. $$
Hence
$$T(n) \leqslant 2 + 2^{h+1}(h-1)\leqslant 2 + 2^{\lg n}(\lg n - 1)= 2 + n(\lg n -1)\leqslant 2n\lg n + 2.$$

Comment: How did you find the last part of the solution (... <=  2n*lg(n) + 2 )

Comment: $n(\lg n-1) = n\lg n - n \leqslant n\lg n + n\lg n = 2n\lg n$